# Access Mail.app database

Tags: macos, cocoa, frameworks

Is there a streamlined way to access and work on top of the Mail.app database? A framework to read both the account information the user has set up and also the mails that are stored in the DB?

Answer (score 2):

I've now finally found a great resource after trying different **search keywords**:
http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.21/21.09/ScriptingMail/index.html

The article provides a great overview on how to access the Mail.app database using **AppleScript**.

Comment: That's from 2005. I'm not saying it's not still useful, but as a heads-up to people reading this solution, I'd like to point out that a lot might have changed.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen it and tested out some of the snippets from the article. Fortunately they still seem to work.